# How to set a docker ARG to an array?

Tags: docker

I have a line in my Dockerfile that's trying to set an ARG to an array.  I've tried it a couple different ways:

```
ARG rubies_to_install=('2.5.5' '2.6.2')
ARG rubies_to_install=(2.5.5 2.6.2)
```

When I build the image, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 9: ARG requires exactly one argument
```

What's the correct way to set a docker arg to an array of strings?

Comment: This is not possible. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Comment: What’s your use case?  A Docker image usually packages a single application, and installing multiple versions of the same language runtime in the same image is a little odd.

Comment: We're using Docker to containerize our "development environment" instead of a single app.  We were previously using a VM + vagrant to manage our dev environments, but we have to quickly move to Docker.  I agree that's it's not an ideal use of Docker, but this strategy will allow us to quickly transition our team (with minimal disruption), until we can get everyone trained up.

Comment: In the case that items don't contain spaces, see this for a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/63166856/2050226