# How can I pass array into a dockerfile and loop through it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am calling the docker build command from a shell script and I wanna pass an array in the build args .. First question can I really do that ? If yes then how do i iterate inside the docker file.
A Small example will really help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass a space-separated string to builds then convert string to an array or just loop over the string.

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
ARG items
RUN for item in $items; do \
    echo "$item"; \
    done;
```

pass value during build time

```
docker build --build-arg items="item1 item2 item3 item4" -t my_image .
```

output

```
Step 3/3 : RUN for item in $items; do     echo "$item";     done;
 ---> Running in bee1fd1dd3c6
item1
item2
item3
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the keyword **ARG RELEASE=master** inside the Dockerfile and and then pass the argument at the time of docker build as **--build-arg RELEASE=v0.1.0**.

The below link give you completed example of the same.

https://blog.dockbit.com/making-use-of-docker-build-arguments-68792d751f3